# Automating ArcMap with ArcObjects for unit testing?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, arcgis-license-manager

I need to run unit tests against ArcMap extension which closely coupled with specific edit workspace and map state. When I try to initialize ArcMap 10 application with code like this:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
IDocument pdoc = new MxDocumentClass();
_application = pdoc.Parent;
```

I receive error:

> The runtime application type must be specified before license initialization

Is there any workaround or better way for unit testing?

Comment: Just curious, are you using a unit testing framework and if so which one? Are you [mocking ArcObjects](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/how-to-unit-test-arcobjects-with-mocking)?

Comment: Using standard VS2010 testing framework. I'm not mocking AO, using ArcMap automation & PGDB. Later in my project, I plan to fascade AO with custom abstract API based on OGC Simple Feature. Then it will be more realistic to use mocking.

Answer (score 7):

Adding this line fixes the issue

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.BindLicense(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
```